# How can I change the scale labeling in ChromaticityPLot3D while keeping the rest unchanged?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, color

I wish to have a 3D chromaticity plot for `LAB` color space. It can be easily done using

```
ChromaticityPlot3D["LAB", "LAB"]
```

However, conventionally, `L` ranges from `0` to `100`, `a*` ranges from `-128` to `127` and `b` ranges from `-128` to `127`. Therefore, I want to change **only the text** (and no change in the scaling) as follows

[image]

[image]

How can I do this?

Comment: `Show[ChromaticityPlot3D[ ...], Ticks ->(*lookup ticks syntax*)]`

Comment: @Kuba I don't see any scale labels after doing this.

Comment: I don't see any code to refer to but I guess you didn't specify at which values which labels should appear.

Comment: `Show[ChromaticityPlot3D["LAB", "LAB"], 
 Ticks -> {{0, 50, 100}, {-128, 0, 127}, {-128, 0, 127}}]`

Comment: Yep, please read `Ticks's` documentation. You didn't specify where should e.g. label `50` appear. The range is always the same so you just specified that you want a tick `50` to appear, not that you want `50` at `0.5`.

Comment: @Kuba Thanks a lot.